# Trigger css hover in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm working a coin flip minigame and I need an animation. My code so far is:

HTML:

```
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YS84SGq.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/lDR0Xj8.png" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flip-container 
{
    position: absolute;
    perspective: 1000;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin-top: 25%;
}

.flip-container, .flip-container .front, .flip-container .back 
{
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.front img, .back img
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.flip-container .flipper 
{
    transition: 3s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

.flip-container .flipper .front, .flip-container .flipper .back 
{
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.flip-container .flipper .front 
{
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flip-container .flipper .back 
{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper 
{
    transform: rotateY(720deg);
}
```

A working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/k0pjcftp/

As you can see, animation works fine on hover. But I need to trigger it somehow through javascript, and I have no idea how. I tried adding a css class with `transform(...)` but animation wasn't working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jQuery's hover method](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) and toggle the `hover` class on your container.

```js
$('.flip-container').hover(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

```css
.flip-container 
{
 position: absolute;
 perspective: 1000;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 margin-top: 25%;
}

.flip-container, .flip-container .front, .flip-container .back 
{
 -moz-border-radius: 150px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
 border-radius: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.front img, .back img
{
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
}

.flip-container .flipper 
{
 transition: 3s;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 position: relative;
}

.flip-container .flipper .front, .flip-container .flipper .back 
{
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
.flip-container .flipper .front 
{
 z-index: 2;
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flip-container .flipper .back 
{
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/*.flip-container:hover .flipper,*/ .flip-container.hover .flipper 
{
 transform: rotateY(720deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
     <div class="front">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YS84SGq.png" alt="" />
     </div>
     <div class="back">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/lDR0Xj8.png" alt="" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Little bit of misunderstanding here. I need to launch the animation as soon as my timer ends, no matter is user hovering this or not. Any way to do that?

Comment: What timer?  You can just toggle the `.hover` class whenever you need to.

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it just make the animation working on hover, I need to just launch the animation, whatever is user doing.